# How to tokenize a sentence splitting on spaces, except treat quoted segments as a single token?

Tags: javascript, tokenize

For example I want to split following sentence:

`(Quick brown "fox     jumps (over)") the lazy dog and (looks for food)`

Expected Output Array:

`["(Quick","brown","fox     jumps (over)",")the","lazy","dog","and","(looks","for","food)"]`

I have tried this simple function in typescript playground:

```
const tokenizeSentenceText = (sentence: any = '') => {
 let wordList = [];

  wordList = sentence.match(/\\?.|^$/g).reduce((p: any, c: any) => {
    if (c === '"') {
        p.quote ^= 1;
    } else if (!p.quote && c === ' ') {
        p.a.push('');
    } else {
        p.a[p.a.length - 1] += c.replace(/\\(.)/, "$1");
    }
    return p;
}, { a: [''] }).a;

return wordList; }
```

Getting output something like this:

`["(Quick", "brown", "fox     jumps (over))", "the", "lazy", "dog", "and", "(looks", "for", "food)"]`

As you can see "fox     jumps (over))" the last closing bracket written outside of double quotes is coming alongside inside the word (over)) instead of (over) and the last closing bracket after the quotes should actually go to the next word ")the"

Note: Anything written inside double quotes " " should be treated as single word. There can be multiple spaces/brackets present inside the double quotes.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Why do you expect `")the"` if there is a space between `)` and `the` in the input? Try `return setence.match(/"[^"]*"|[^\s"]+/g)` and see if it works more or less the way you need. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LA5CAd/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm about to accomplish whay OP wants but just a slight difference, Would you please take a look `str
  .replace(/\s/g, "_")
  .replace(/("[^"]+)/, (...args) => {
    return args[0].replaceAll("_", " ");
  })
  .split("_")
  .filter((_) => _);`

Comment: please don't tag spam. Also, there is nothing Typescript specific to this question (TS is JS with types)

Comment: @WiktorStribizew - Thanks allot for your answer. I came up with this regex [^\s\)\("]+|(?:"|'){2,}|"(?!")([^"]*)"|'(?!')([^']*)'|"|'  and its somewhat solving my use case. Thanks again.

Comment: @ShravanC But [it does not match all the strings](https://regex101.com/r/LA5CAd/2). Shall I post my initial solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use

```js
const tokenizeSentenceText = (sentence) => {
  return sentence.match(/"[^"]*"|[^\s"]+/g);
}
// If the double quotes need removing 
const tokenizeSentenceTextNoQuotes = (sentence) => {
  return Array.from(sentence.matchAll(/"([^"]*)"|[^\s"]+/g), (x) => x[1] ?? x[0]);
}

const text = '(Quick brown "fox     jumps (over)") the lazy dog and (looks for food)';
console.log(tokenizeSentenceText(text))
console.log(tokenizeSentenceTextNoQuotes(text))
```

The regex matches

- `"([^"]*)"` - a `"` char, any zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"` char
- `|` - or
  -`[^\s"]+` - one or more chars other than whitespace and `"` chars.

The `(x) => x[1] ?? x[0]` in `Array.from(sentence.matchAll(/"([^"]*)"|[^\s"]+/g), (x) => x[1] ?? x[0])` returns Group 1 value if that alternative got matched, else, the whole match is returned (what was matched with `[^\s"]+`).